# Why is the "la chose" replaced by "le" instead of "la" in the following sentence?

Tags: pronoms, genre

> Quelle est la seule chose que vous faites en privé qui pourrait vous embarrasser si le public **le** savait ?

I came across this question on French Quora. Shouldn't the ending be “*la savait*”, cause “*la seule chose*” is feminine?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The antecedent of *le* here is not *la chose*, but the clause « que vous faites cette chose ». This is given *le*, masculine singular, only because that functions as the default inflection when gender and number don't apply.

It's definitely tempting to find the nearest noun for a given pronoun. But certain pronouns, especially *le* and *en*, tend to associate themselves with implied elements of the discourse:

> Est-ce que tu as bien aimé Anne ? Et dire qu'aujourd'hui, tu le regrettes.
>
> [Personne n'a écrit un livre sur comment en lire.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19724/why-is-there-an-en-in-personne-na-%C3%A9crit-un-livre-sur-comment-en-lire)

It might be helpful to realize that in English, we often give these elements *no* pronoun at all. We just omit them:

> — He's coming back at midnight. *Il revient à minuit.*
>
>  — I know. *Je **le** sais.*

Here *le* refers to « qu'il revient à minuit », but there's no corresponding *it* for "that he's coming back at midnight".

Comment: merci beaucoup!

Comment: This is no doubt correct but I am struggling to see why "Quelle" agrees but "le" does not given they surely refer to the same thing.

Comment: @abligh No reason why to assume they refer to the same thing. *Quelle* stands for *quelle chose*. "What (thing, fem.) is the one thing you do in private that could embarrass you if the public knew... " — How should we complete that sentence? Not with "...said thing" (fem.) but with "...that you did it" (masc., by default).

Comment: To the list of vague pronouns in the answer we could add *ce*, *ça*. Unlike *quel*, those ones can and often do refer to implied phrases instead of nearby nouns.

Comment: I would add that one *could* say "I know it" in English, and that "it" in that case replaces the (implied) dependent clause "that he is coming back at midnight."

Comment: @phoog Indeed, though more likely is "I know that"